# Pandas Dataframe resample week, starting first day of the year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resampling, week-number

I have a dataframe containing hourly data, i want to get the max for each week of the year, so i used resample to group data by week

```
weeks = data.resample("W").max()
```

the problem is that week max is calculated starting the first monday of the year, while i want it to be calculated starting the first day of the year.

I obtain the following result, where you can notice that there is 53 weeks, and the last week is calculated on the next year while 2017 doesn't exist in the data

```
Date        dots       
2016-01-03  0.647786
2016-01-10  0.917071
2016-01-17  0.667857
2016-01-24  0.669286
2016-01-31  0.645357


Date        dots                
2016-12-04  0.646786
2016-12-11  0.857714
2016-12-18  0.670000
2016-12-25  0.674571
2017-01-01  0.654571
```

is there a way to calculate week for pandas dataframe starting first day of the year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick remedy is, given you data in one year, you can group it by day first, then take group of 7 days:

```
new_df = (df.resample("D", on='Date').dots
            .max().reset_index()
         )

new_df.groupby(new_df.index//7).agg({'Date': 'min', 'dots': 'max'})

new_df.head()
```

Output:

```
    Date        dots
0   2016-01-01  0.996387
1   2016-01-08  0.999775
2   2016-01-15  0.997612
3   2016-01-22  0.979376
4   2016-01-29  0.998240
5   2016-02-05  0.995030
6   2016-02-12  0.987500
```

and tail:

```
    Date        dots
48  2016-12-02  0.999910
49  2016-12-09  0.992910
50  2016-12-16  0.996877
51  2016-12-23  0.992986
52  2016-12-30  0.960348
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is what i was looking for, have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

Find the starting day of the year, for example let say it's Friday, and then you can specify an [anchoring suffix](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets) to resample in order to calculate week starting first day of the year:
`weeks = data.resample("W-FRI").max()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes this can be considered when you already know the starting day of the year, however i have a lot of data for many years, so this solution won't be interesting.